# Accessing other outlook folders

Tags: c#, outlook

I think I figured this out using this code,

```
oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
oNS = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
oNS.Logon(null, null, false, false);

QSourceFolder = oNS.Folders["qsource inc"];

string folderName = "Clutter";


try
{
oSubfolder = QSourceFolder.Folders[folderName];

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem in oSubfolder.Items)
subject = mailItem.Subject;
```

but when I try to loop through the emails in this folder I get the following error message:

[image]

[image: Outlook folders]

I am trying to figure out how can I access a specific folder using C# that is part of another email account other than my own. I have the ability to see emails that are sent to the widget inc email account, and I want to programmatically examine any emails that are sent to it. Specifically I want to see any emails that get kicked back due to a bad email address, and these are being put in the Clutter folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that you can only have `MailItem` objects in a the folder. You can have `MailItem`, `ReportItem`, `MeetingItem` etc. - use a generic "object" instead of MailItem and use the "`as`" operator to cast to a specific interface with the subsequent check for null.